# Conditional creation of a series from other series

Tags: pandas

Say I have two series `s1` and `s2` where  `s2` includes all indices of `s1` and a few more.

I would like to obtain a third series `s3` with the same indices as `s2` where:

- If the index is in `s1`, `s3` gets the value in `s1`
- Otherwise, get the value already present in `s2`

How can I do this in Pandas? I first thought I could do this with a `join` or `concat` operation, but I don't think that would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.update.html) to do this inplace:

```
In [11]: s1 = pd.Series([1, 2])

In [12]: s2 = pd.Series([3, 4, 5])

In [13]: s3 = s2.copy()  # update is inplace, so let's do this on a copy

In [14]: s3.update(s1)

In [15]: s3
Out[15]:
0    1
1    2
2    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot @Andy That's the right way to do it (i.e. as with dictionaries)

Comment: Congrats on getting to 40k! Your contributions are extremely helpful.